# Elementary OS7 Horus, horrible colour cast

Tags: updates, color, horus

Just upgraded my miniPC from Elementary OS6 to OS7 and my screen (iiyama 27") has an awful blue/green colour cast. eos5 and eos6 ran perfectly, no problems with colour balance but eos7 is unuseable unless I can sort this problem.

Any suggestions?

Neil

PS When starting eos7, the colour balance of the login screen is fine but when the login screen clears the colour cast returns.
PPS Have upgraded my HP laptop to eos7 without any issues.

Comment: have you nvidia gpu?

Comment: Not sure but don't think so. The miniPC is one of the all-in-one aluminium box types.